# Python always says very strong when It's above 8 characters

Tags: python, debugging

The password strength indicator is always telling me "very strong" if it is more than or equal to 8 characters of any type

Before my code always had syntax errors, but now it doesn't even tell me what's wrong and I've looked in many other places but I can't find it.
Here is code:

```
print('This program measures the strength of your password. It is safe.')
# Input password.

password = input('Please enter your trial password:')

# Check password.

if len(password) >=8 and password.isalnum():
    print('You have a very strong password.')
elif len(password) >=8 and password.isalpha():
    print('You have a strong password.')
```

So it always says that the password is very strong as long as it is greater than or equal to 8 characters, but I just want it to say "very strong" only if the code has numbers, and letters and preferably special characters too. I am trying to make "very strong" identify as a password greater than or equal to 8 characters, and  has letters and at least one number.

Comment: *Read* the documentation for 'isalnum'?

Comment: `isalnum` is true if it has alphabetic **or** numeric characters, it doesn't have to have both.

Comment: (Also, this would [have] be[en] a good question to show input and [unexpected] output, as that should also quickly reveal "the issue".)

Comment: Use regular expressions, I don't think there are any built-in functions that will do what you want.

Comment: Search SO for **[regex] password strength** and you'll find some solutions.